# LibGDX: Skin and scaling problems

Tags: libgdx, scene2d

I'm trying to use Skins with TextButtons. However I'm having an issue where the TextureRegions of the Skin are NOT being scaled down to the tablesize.

This is leading to an issue like in this image:

[image]

As you can see that is the e from the word Hello. I managed to scale that down to a more reasonable size (still wrong). However the Button textures are still way too large.

[image]

Any ideas? Because I am pulling my hair out. I am using a custom viewport with a custom screenspace width and height. Here is the create method for the menu.

```
    public void create(){
    menuStage = new Stage();
    camera = new OrthographicCamera();
    viewPort = new StretchViewport(SCREEN_SPACE_WIDTH, SCREEN_SPACE_HEIGHT, camera);
    viewPort.setWorldSize(SCREEN_SPACE_WIDTH, SCREEN_SPACE_HEIGHT);
    menuStage.setViewport(viewPort);

    devTexture = new Sprite (new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("data/16by9.png"), true));


    Image newActor = new Image(devTexture.getTexture());
    newActor.setSize(
            viewPort.getWorldWidth(),
            viewPort.getWorldHeight()
    );

    menuStage.addActor(newActor);
    skin = new Skin(Gdx.files.internal("data/uiskin.json"));

    menuTable = new Table();

    skin.getFont("default-font").setScale(0.08f);

    menuTable.debugAll();

    menuTable.setFillParent(true);
    TextButton a,b,c;

    a = new TextButton("hello", skin);
    b = new TextButton("hello", skin);
    c = new TextButton("hello", skin);

    a.getStyle().up.setMinWidth(2.0f);

    b.getStyle().up.setMinHeight(2.0f);
    b.getStyle().up.setMinWidth(2.0f);

    c.getStyle().up.setMinHeight(2.0f);
    c.getStyle().up.setMinWidth(2.0f);

    menuTable.row();
    menuTable.add(a).size(2.0f, 1.0f);
    menuTable.add(b).size(2.0f, 1.0f);
    menuTable.add(c).size(2.0f, 1.0f);

    menuStage.addActor(menuTable);

    camera.translate(
            newActor.getWidth() / 2,
            newActor.getHeight() / 2
    );
}
```